Casement Window Not Closing Fully
It seems like the crank just stops when the window is about an inch away from closing.


Occasionally, gears in the crank assembly can be stripped. However, if that were the case, the handle would keep turning, without effect.
Your video clearly shows the window is stuck, so it's unlikely the crank/arm operator is broken. Check for something blocking full closure.

Look for something around the edge of the frame blocking closure. Some likely obstructions are the latch for the window (e.g., it is flipped to the locked position), a pebble, or a warped frame.
Look at the operator arms, underneath the window. The arm pivot may have slipped out of a slot, and needs to be put back in place. (The operator arms often can be detached to allow the window to open a full 90° for cleaning.)
If 1. or 2. is not the fault, unscrew the cover of the arm operator and look for debris obstructing gears.


An obstruction near the hinge would not need to be big.
